# Conexion Access 2016 Oracle 12G Enterprise

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, odbc, ms-access-2013

Me han dado credenciales de acceso para conectarme a una base de datos Oracle 12G Enterprise 64BITS (Solo Lectura)

Necesito vincular las tablas de esa base de datos via ODBC desde Access 2016.

He visto algunas instrucciones usando el controlador de access "ODBC for Oracle" pero al intentar usarlo este me lanza error, entonces tengo que instalar algu driver adicional?

Pueden ayudarme a realizar la conexion?

Tengo Windows 10 de 64BITS
Office 365 de 32BITS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: instalaste el cliente de oracle?

Comment: @gbianchi
Descargue un driver de la pagina de Oracle pero creo no es el correcto o bien no identifique cual es el instalador. Necesitaria verificarlo en el trabajo.

Comment: y entonces no se que podemos contestarte.. porque el error es que te falta el cliente de ora.. se llama ora_client

Comment: @gbianchi
Los tutoriales que encontre no veo que descarguen algun driver, directamente lo hacen con el ODBC for Oracle que puse en la imagen.
Por ello lance la pregunta, entonces el driver correcto es ora_client de cuantos BITS sera el necesario de 32 o 64 mi Access es de 32BITS, Windows de 64BITS y la base oracle es de 64BITS.

Comment: el de tu windows...y tal vez lo tenian ya instalado, no puedo decirte sobre cosas que no vi, pero el driver **no viene** con windows

Comment: @gbianchi
Edite la pregunta agregando una nueva imagen, creo ese es el driver correcto salvo me diga lo contrario. Si es el correcto como comienzo la conexion?

Comment: Pero eso es un cliente de mysql, que tiene que ver con oracle?

Comment: windows lista las conexiones odbc por alguna razon extra;a pero igual requieres instalar el [oracle client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) y debera apareserte un nuevo odbc oracle con el que ya te permitira hacer la conexion que solo dira `oracle in oracleDB11GHome`!

Comment: @Bryro
Edite de nuevo la pregunte la ultima imagen adjunto es el que ya he descargado desde ayer, ese es el driver correcto?

Comment: @gbianchi
No se que parte es la que estas viendo pero no es MySQL, es oracle la carpeta mostrada en la imagen.

Comment: ya te pasaron un link, eso es lo que tenes que bajar. e instalar

Comment: @gbianchi
Pues he descargado el driver y no me aparece en mi origenes de datos, para poder configurarlo.